# How to marge created barcode image in Django 2?

Tags: django, python-3.x, image, barcode

I was trying to create a barcode image and I did that successfully. But the problem is now I want to merge them in one image like the user will say I need 4 images then the system will generate **one image of 4 barcodes**
where the barcode ***weight*** is **4** cm and ***height*** is **2** cm

**View.py**

```
import barcode
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter

@login_required(login_url='loginPage')
def printBarCode(request):
    barCodeImage = barcode.get('Code128', '12345678910', writer=ImageWriter())
    file = barCodeImage.save(barCodeImage)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

**The image I get**

[image]

**The image I want**

[image]

Comment: why aren't you creating 4 images for 4 barcodes?

Comment: Do you want 4 barcodes in a single image?

Comment: Yes, brother, I want 4 barcodes image in a single image.

Comment: see https://pypi.org/project/pylabels/